# How do I rebind "Initiate Window Move" to mouse button 10?

Tags: compiz, mouse, window-manager

I am trying to use button 10 on my mouse to drag windows around.  I have installed CCSM and changed the initiate button in the plugin "Move Window" to "Button10" (with no modifier, though adding modifier keys to test does not help).

I know that the desired button is number 10 because `xev` reports

```
ButtonPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x15d, subw 0x0, time 8361012, (77,129), root:(1812,182),
    state 0x0, button 10, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
root 0x15d, subw 0x0, time 8361286, (77,129), root:(1812,182),
    state 0x0, button 10, same_screen YES
```

when I click that button in its window.

There is no effect when pressing button 10 with these settings.  However, I know that I'm changing the correct setting, as switching from the default of Alt+Button1 to e.g. Ctrl+Alt+Button1 does take effect.

Edit: output of `xinput list --long 10` as requested by Braiam.

```
Logitech Gaming Mouse G400                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 5 classes:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 16
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" "Button Side" "Button Extra" "Button Forward" "Button Back" "Button Task" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown" "Button Unknown"
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Vert Wheel
          Range: -1.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 10. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: -1.000000
          flags: 0x2 ( preferred )
```

Comment: i would be led to think that the button is called 10 .. but in binary form.. (which translates to the number 2 in base10 :)
this isn't an answer.. just an attempt at clarification .. i suggest it.. but i may be wrong !
and i honestly don't know where to write this.. :)

Comment: Have you tried "b:10" instead of "Button10"?

Comment: I'm choosing Button10 from a drop-down in the graphical dialog, not typing it in.  If I edit the field with the text-box dialog, and type "b:10" it reverts to "Disabled".

Comment: @P-Nuts could you add `xinput list --long 10` to your output?

Comment: Have you trid bindng it to say button 1 just for kicks to make sure it works out that way? to make sure everything else is set properly? PPL please feel free yto rephrase what I'm trying to say...

Comment: The mouse I had when I asked this question stopped working a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the setting in CCSM? Try **`<ALT> Button 10`**. I believe you might have to use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> button to initiate the move. "Do not quote me". I am just taking a guess.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to use mouse buttons in that keyboard settings window.

Comment: @P-Nuts I do believe you might be correct. I should have investigated further. Sorry about the wrong info...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager), go to the **Window Management** section, and find the **Move Windows** icon.
2. Make sure **Move Window** is enabled, and then Click it's button.

[image]

3. Click the button to the right of the **Initiate Move Window** with the mouse icon next to it.

[image]

4. In the **Edit Initiate Window Move** window, make sure the **Shift**, **Super**, **Ctrl**, and **Alt** buttons are disable (black, not green), and select **Button 10** in the drop-down list.  Also make sure all the screen edges are disabled (red, not green).

[image]